# I'm geting the " ld returned 1 exit status " error, how do i find the the hidden error

Tags: c++, sorting, fstream

i understand that this error means that there are hiden errors that have not bin located, I'm just having a hard time fingering out were those errors are. **please give me some pointers on how to find the unknown error.**

over the " ld returned 1 exit status " error are these two errors

- undefined reference to `MyList::count'
- bad reloc address 0x1 in
  section.text$_ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_[_ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_]

my progect consists of

- `getData()` to read info form a txt
- `sortData()` to sort the info
- `saveData()` to save the info in a txt

here is the class and the program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class MyList{
    private: 
        int info2[100][2], info[100][2];
        int count = 0;
    public:
        void getData(string);
        void saveData(string);
        void sortData();
};
void MyList::getData(string a){
    int i;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(a.c_str());
        if(!file.is_open()){
            cout << " File did not open, can not read" <<endl;
            return;
        }
        for(i=0; ;i++){
            file >> info[i][0] >> info[i][1];
            if(file.eof()){
                break;
            }
        }
        count=i;
    file.close();
}

void MyList::sortData(){
    ifstream file;
    int i,a,b,c,flag=1;
    int j=0;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        for(i=0;(i<=count-1) && flag;i++){
            if(info[i][a] < info[i+1][a]){

                info2[b][c] = info[i][a];
                info[i][a] = info[i+1][a];
                info[i+1][a] = info2[b][c];
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
void MyList::saveData(string a){
    int i;
    ofstream file(a.c_str());
        if(!file.is_open()){
            cout << " File did not open, can not save" <<endl;
            return;
        }
    for(i=0;i>=count;i++){
        file << info[i][0] << info[i][1];
    }
}


#include <iostream>
#include "aList.h"
using namespace std;
```

> here's the project that is giving the error

```
int main(){
    MyList obj;
    string fileName;

    cout << " what is your files name? :";
    cin >>fileName;
    obj.getData(fileName);
    obj.sortData();
    obj.saveData(fileName);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where did you define `MyList::count`? the declaration is in the class, but the definition is missing.

Comment: i defined it in the private section

Comment: That is the declaration, not the definition. See the duplicate question for more details.

Comment: As a fun side note, `ofstream file(a.c_str())` is not needed, ofstream has an overload for `std::string`: `ofstream file(a)` is fine.

Comment: @Wimmel i get it now (what a definition is ) and adding the definition fixed the error thanks.

Comment: @Wimmel the compiler is just giving me a warning that "initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]" do you know what this means?

Comment: You should add to your cpp file this line: `int MyList::count=0;` Did you do that?

Comment: @Wimmel ya i did that and removed the static because i noticed i didn't need it

Comment: @Wimmel and it works I'm just curious about the warning

Comment: Then I don't understand the warning. I thought you changed something else.